# Add selenium data to excel PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I have a problem. I have a code that using selenium and getting information form different sites and put then into one list. And after all, python will delete all information in the list, I need to write them to the excel:

```
List = []
for values in List:
      ...
      List.append(values)
      List.append(some_information_from_selenium)
```

And in the end of iteration:

```
List.clear()
```

I need to save information before clear() and after cleat List, add new information to the excel. This iteration have limit - 100. Need to create a new excel file, and adding information to this. List will delete and then append new information, this iteration will be 100 times. I will have 18 columns and 100 rows. I can use whatever i want.

:UPD:

One more question: if i use

```
data = pd.DataFrame() 
data({ "Name":List[some_index] 
       "Surname":List[some_index_1] 
        .... }) 
data.to_excel("Excel.xlsx")
```

Why I got error **'DataFrame' object is not callable** and how can i solve this

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough information / code in your question to support you. What excel file, how is data written to this file, etc ...

Comment: `import pandas as pd`;`df = pd.Dataframe({'data' : List})`;`df.to_excel` but as @pintxo has said, please provide a [mcve] and see [ask]

Comment: @Manakin ive changed question .

Comment: why do you clear your list after 100 entries? better to use a dictionary and hold each iteration in a seperate variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do from your code, but instead of clearing your list variable each time, let's hold it in some sort of nested collection.

A simple dictionary will do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data_dict = defaultdict(list)

for num in range(10,110,10): #call your func in iterations of 10s
    your code
    data_dict[i].append(some_information_from_selenium)
```

Each iteration of 10 will hold your nested data:

```
data_dict[10]
```

which you can then pass into pandas.

Comment: Hmmmm, got it, and can you say, if i use 
data = pd.DataFrame()
    data({
        "Name":List[some_index]
        "Surname":List[some_index_1]
         ....
   })
    data.to_excel("Excel.xlsx")
Why I got 'DataFrame' object is not callable and how can i solve this

Comment: @Kate_Sls I'm sorry I can't help you if you don't provide a [mcve] I can't see your data, your ccde or anything that's happening.

Comment: i added some information into my question. Can you check it?